# Creating a title for a question that has unclear question

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask if asking a question like "how to create a website like this?" is acceptable? Right now I don't know how to create [this](http://www.warzelnia.com/pl/warzelnia-informacje) kind of site.

I want to create a site like that and I'm looking for tutorials, but I don't know what title is fitting due to certain reason such as

1. I don't know what framework it is.
2. I'm having difficulty reading the code
3. What I want to ask is tutorials to create that kind of website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to ask if asking a question like "how to create a website like this?" is acceptable?

No, it is not appropriate for SO. It is "too broad" and, possibly, "unclear what you are asking".

> I don't know what framework it is.

This really isn't relevant. It can be created with any(?) framework. You need to decide what you want to develop with, start, and ask when you get stuck on a specific problem.

> I'm having difficulty reading the codes

Reading what "codes"? And please don't say "codes" on SO...you will be persecuted. It is "code". You need to work on creating your own code from your own learning through books, tutorials, etc... which you can find plenty to begin with on The Google.

> What I want to ask is tutorials to create that kind of website

Definitely don't do this! It is [explicitly against SO practices for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

**My advice to you**...

Use Google, start learning whatever language and/or framework you are comfortable with. There is plenty of documentation and tutorials to get you started. Then ask on SO if/when you are stuck on a specific problem.

**In conclusion**

I don't want to come off sounding harsh. We all appreciate you asking here when uncertain. However, a question like that is *extremely* off-topic for SO.

*In full disclosure: I'm not a web dev but, IMO, that website is terrible. Set your sites higher*

Comment: I'd also add, you can't just jump into creating a site like x,y,z. You have to work up to it. That takes practise and study to solve the smaller problems such a site will bring and only then do you build complex sites. However, that site is not complex, and is an example of what not to do.

Comment: I agree with @user3791372, but I'd add that any question that starts with `How do I create a site like X?` is going down the wrong path. Don't try to make your website look like others that you admire: let the function of the website determine its initial design and allow a professional designer to create the final design, because they know what they're doing (unless you're a designer *and* a web dev, in which case I commend you for having both skills, but my advice about mimicking other sites stands).

Comment: "allow a professional designer to create the final design, because they know what they're doing" e.g. They know who to copy from without being caught. :)